# parsing wsdl file with wsdl2java result in error message

Tags: java, xml, wsdl, wsdl2java, mantis

I'm trying to generate java client stubs from a wsdl file, but this results in a cumbersome error message:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGener
>   ationEngine.java:293)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SimpleDBExtension.engage(Simp
>   leDBExtension.java:53)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:246)
>           ... 2 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SimpleDBExtension.engage(SimpleDBExtension.java:50)
>           ... 3 more Caused by: org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompilationException: can not find type
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}Array from the parent
>   schema http://futureware.biz/mantisconnect
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.copyMetaInfoHierarchy(SchemaCompiler.java:1371)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexContent(SchemaCompiler.java:1333)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processContentModel(SchemaCompiler.java:1228)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1172)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1092)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:1006)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:645)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:604)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.process(SchemaCompiler.java:2069)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processParticle(SchemaCompiler.java:1958)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1156)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1092)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:1006)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:645)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:604)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.process(SchemaCompiler.java:2069)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processParticle(SchemaCompiler.java:1952)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1156)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processAnonymousComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1055)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:1009)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:645)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:615)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:423)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:292)
>           at org.apache.axis2.schema.ExtensionUtility.invoke(ExtensionUtility.java:102)
>           ... 8 more

Could anyone tell me what might be the problem here?

Comment: http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl

Answer (score 2):

There are different encoding types of WSDLs like RPC/encoded, RPC/literal, Document/encoded, Document/literal. I think your WSDL is using RPC/encoded. RPC/encoded encoding style is not supported directly by Axis2.

This [article](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/Axis2-rpc-support.html) is about using RPC/encoded WSDLs with Axis2. I hope this will help.